# CSS not working in JSF 2.0 project

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2, twitter-bootstrap-3

My JSF 2.0 web project isn't rendering graphics from CSS. It loads images but it cannot load any background color or anything at all. Am I doing anything wrong here? My CSS file contains code for coloring and other things. I am using Bootstrap. My output page is plain black and white. I do not see any error messages in Eclipse.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <h:head>
    <f:facet name="meta-tags">
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Aayush Mittal</title>
    </f:facet>


    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <f:facet name="css-files">
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/bootstrap.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/additional.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800"></h:outputStylesheet>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
    </f:facet>


    <f:facet name="js-files">
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <h:outputScript  name="js/bootstrap.min.js"></h:outputScript>
        <h:outputScript name="js/custom.js"></h:outputScript>
    </f:facet>

  </h:head>

  <h:body class="main-body" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-collapse1" data-offset="50">

    <div class="container-fluid body-prop1" id="home">
        <div class="container-fluid section-contents">
            <h1 class="welcome-text">Hola, Amigo!</h1>
            <div class="container-fluid personal-info">
                <p class="personal-info-text">
                    This website is my experiment with Bootstrap framework. I will try to put up my college projects and personal projects live here. I would also add some interesting stuff
                    including some blog posts. Feel free to "Stalk" me on Twitter, check out my code on GitHub, or just shoot me an Email if you find anything interesting. 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



  </h:body>
</html>
```

This is my directory structure for the project:

[image]

Comment: Also, I did try using a /resource folder under WebContent but that didn't work at all. That way not even the image could load. I rewrote the code to make it work in JSF 2. Initially it was in HTML and CSS and it worked like a charm.

Comment: look in your javascript console and see if there are any 404 (or other script) errors

Comment: I do not have any errors. Also, it displays images. It just doesn't show me the CSS properties applied.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I transferred all the folders - images, js, fonts, and css to a resources directory and moved that directory under WEB-INF folder. After that, I added following code to my web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>
 javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY
</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/resources</param-value>
```

And that made things to work. Now that I am following the official pattern of using the resources folder here, I had to get rid of relative paths and use only file names. Names of the folders that the files are in go to the library attribute. For example:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/bootstrap.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
```

becomes

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
```

Also, the resources folder can be put in the WebContent directory as well as long as you put all that information in web.xml. I am writing these instructions just in case someone gets stuck on the same thing!